# Can someone explain me what this line of ruby code does?

Tags: ruby, backend

I'm a beginner in ruby and found this example on the Odin project about the reduce method, but in **line 7** it puts the result variable again, can someone explain me What's the use of putting the result variable?

Thank you in advance!

```
votes = ["Bob's Dirty Burger Shack", "St. Mark's Bistro", "Bob's Dirty Burger Shack"]

votes.reduce(Hash.new(0)) do |result, vote|
  puts "result is #{result} and votes is #{vote}"
  puts "This is result [vote]: #{result[vote]}"
  result[vote] += 1
  result #this part I don't understand
end
```

Comment: [`Enumerable#reduce`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're using the `reduce(initial_operand) {|memo, operand| ... }` version.

`memo` is a thing to collect the result. The block has to pass that along to the next iteration. For example, if you wanted to sum up a list of numbers...

```
(1..4).inject do |sum, element|
  p "Running sum: #{sum}; element: #{element}"

  # This is passed along to the next iteration as sum.
  sum + element
end
```

Instead of using the default `memo`, which would be the first element, they've used `Hash.new(0)` to count the votes. Each iteration counts the votes, and then passes the result has to the next iteration.

```
# result starts as Hash.new(0)
votes.reduce(Hash.new(0)) do |result, vote|
  # This prints the state of the voting and the current choice being tallied.
  puts "result is #{result} and votes is #{vote}"

  # This displays how many votes there are for this choice at this point
  # before this choice is tallied.
  puts "This is result [vote]: #{result[vote]}"

  # This adds the vote to the tally.
  result[vote] += 1

  # This passes along the tally to the next iteration.
  result
end
```

If you don't want to print on each iteration, use [`tally`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally) instead.

```
result = votes.tally
```